# Create a reusable function to open and send Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have noted that in my program every time when I want to declare a object, for example list, save, add, remove I write the following every time in each function.

```
ajax.open("Get", "./route/action",true);     
ajax.send();
```

I want to do something like this.

```
//this.ajax.get('./route/action').update('ajax-content');
./route/action // this is path to my Action class-using servlet
```

Every time I have to open a connection, give the path to my action class which is a `servlet` and then send. I do this every time I want to load a list, delete or update.

How can I write a function that I will be just be:

```
this.ajax.get('./route/action');
// 'ajax.content' is the id of the div where I 
// want to show the list,where after updating AJAX show the update list to the user.
update('ajax-content');
```

For example after adding a user I can see the added user without reloading the whole page. I am working on a maven project using Java EE, Servlet and JavaScript.

Comment: use as a callback....!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ajaxRequest(AJAXurl, callbackElementID){
   x = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
   x.open("get", AJAXurl, true);
   x.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById(callbackElementID).innerHTML = x.responseText; //Will send the received data to the element passed in the function
    }
  };
  x.send();
}
```

Use as following:

```
ajaxRequest("/somefile.php", "elementID"); //This will send recieved data to the element with "elementID" as id
```

**Note:** The way this is built is only for `GET` requests. Change code if you want `POST` request.

Comment: I am using java, servlet, jsp. I have a jsp file where I have used to create a <div id="ajax-content"> where my items are listed. I have a servlet @Webservlet(./route) and I use writer to loop through a list to display the items. My javascript, have an object route that have the attibutes cmp[],list,delete,add. How do I use the ajaxRequest(AJAXurl,callbackElementID). for url I know it will be path to my servlet. what about the callbackElentId.